Inconsistency in Sample Size from Power Calculation Using the Observed Effect Size
My original goal was to confirm, that the input to my power calculation is correct.
For this reason, I used the number I got from my analysis and plunged them into R's power calculation function power.t.test().
My expectation was that I would get the same sample size as used in the study (assuming I use exactly the input parameters from the analysis). However, there was consistently a small difference. What is the reason for this difference?
Details
My intuition would tell me that if the observed effect size (difference and residual standard error) corresponds the true effect size ($H_A$), then in half of future experiments we should get a smaller p-value then observed and in half of the experiments a bigger p-value then observed. Therefore, we should get 50% power in a power analysis with the observed parameter (including p-value as significance level).

Alternatively, I can also fix the 50% power and should get the same sample size as observed.
Below, the output of the analysis, from which I took the input parameters.
set.seed(1)
sample_size <- 5
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(sample_size*2, mean = rep(c(0,1), each = sample_size), sd = 0.8),
                  x = rep(c("a", "b"), each = sample_size))
(s <- summary(lm(y ~ x, data = dat)))
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dat)
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -0.7719 -0.5415  0.1018  0.3348  1.1728 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
## (Intercept)   0.1034     0.2962   0.349   0.7360  
## xb            1.0047     0.4189   2.398   0.0433 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.6623 on 8 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.4183, Adjusted R-squared:  0.3456 
## F-statistic: 5.752 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.04329

The p-value was divided by 2 such that it would correspond to a one-sided test.
power.t.test(delta = 1.004693, sd = 0.662344, sig.level = 0.04328541/2,
             power = 0.5, alternative = "one.sided")
## 
##      Two-sample t test power calculation 
## 
##               n = 4.759026
##           delta = 1.004693
##              sd = 0.662344
##       sig.level = 0.02164271
##           power = 0.5
##     alternative = one.sided
## 
## NOTE: n is number in *each* group

As you can see in the output, the sample size is slightly off by ≈ 0.25 (n = 4.76 instead of 5). If I repeat the simulation for different sample sizes I get the following picture

There is consistently a difference of 0.25 (with lower variance at higher sampling size).
Question

Why does the power calculation result in a lower sample size? What is wrong with my intuition?
Why 0.25? Maybe something with degrees of freedom and how residual standard error ($\frac{SSR}{n-2}$) is estimated?


Look up the non-central t distribution; power is not symmetric like that.

Below you see an example of 10000 simulations for a test of a hypothesis $H_0:\theta = 0$, with a normal distributed sample $X_i \sim  N(\theta,\sigma)$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.
With a t-test the critical region is not when the estimate $\hat{\theta}$ is below or above some level. But instead when the t-statistic $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{s.e.(\hat{\theta})}$ is below or above some level.
Say you observed $\hat\theta = 0.823$ and $\hat{\sigma} = 1$, and consider the sample distribution for that situation, then you get the simulations on the right. The distribution has a symmetry along the vertical line along $\hat\theta = 0.823$ and you have 50%-50% of the sampled $\hat\theta$ above and below the value $0.823$, but that is not the critical region. If the estimated standard error (which depends on the sample standard deviation and is variable from test to test) is low then the critical value for $\hat{\theta}$ is lower. And vice versa, If the estimated standard error is high then the critical value for $\hat{\theta}$ is higher. This breaks the symmetry.


In the special case for n=2, then the sample distribution for the deviation will be a half normal distribution, and the joint distribution of $\hat{\theta}$ and $se(\hat{\theta})$ has a spherical symmetry from which it is easier to see how the diagonal critical line for a t-test doesn't split the cases in 50-50 like the vertical line of a z-test.
It will also depend on the p-value what the power is for an effect size with that given p-value.
In the image below, this time the example observed statistics are $\hat{\theta} =2.176$ and $\hat{\sigma} =1$, giving a p-value of 0.2 for the null hypothesis, and a power of 66% for the hypothetical case that these observed statistics are the true distribution values.


Thanks, very interesting visual way of looking at the problem! About the last part: I agree that the power depends on effect size (and the resulting $p$-value). However, interestingly the sample size to achieve 50% power was consistently 0.25 smaller than the observed sample size (regardless of observed sample size and effect size/$p$-value).

@retodomax I believe that this is just a coincidence and is does depend on the p-value. For example, think of the power when the observed p is very close to 1. Then the hypothetical effect is zero, and the power will be close to the p value. One would need a much larger sample to get to 50% power. (In this case the discrepancy from 50% is because the left tail of the distribution starts to count.

What helped me a lot to understand the problem was @PBulls comment about non-central $t$ distribution. I have included this line of thought in the answer below.
The intuition (raised in the question) is actually wrong. If the true effect size is the one observed then it does not mean that that under repeated sampling we would get on average in half of the cases a smaller $t$-value then observed.
For simplification, we look at a one sample $t$-test.
$$
X_1, \dots, X_9 \sim \text{i.i.d } N(\mu,\sigma^2)
$$
with
$$
\begin{align*}
H_0: \mu &= \mu_0 = 0\\
H_A: \mu &\neq 0
\end{align*}
$$
As true values we assume $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$.
The $t$-statistic for the one-sample $t$-test is calculated as
$$
T = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu_0}{\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n}}
$$
If I plug in the true values instead of the estimators I get
$$
T_{p} = \frac{\mu - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{1/\sqrt{9}} = 3
$$
It could be tempting to assume that under $H_A$

$E(T) = 3$
$T$ is distributed symmetrical around 3

However, non of those is true. In general

$E(\hat{\sigma}^2) = \sigma^2$ but $E(\hat{\sigma}) \neq \sigma$ i.e $\hat{\sigma}$ is not an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$ (see Jensen's inequality)
Even if $\hat{\sigma}$ would be unbiased, in general it would still be that $E(T) \neq T_p$. The reason is that $E(\frac{X}{Y}) \neq \frac{E(X)}{E(Y)}$, also not if $X \perp Y$ (which is the case for $\bar{X}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$).
Even though under $H_0$ the $t$-statistic is symmetric, it is not under $H_A$ where it follows a noncentral $t$-distribution (shown in the picture below with a heavier tail on the right)


The only question which remains is why the sample size was always off by 0.25. Here a function which calculates the difference in $n$ as a function of sig.level and n. It always results something close to 0.25. It would be interesting to understand mathematically why this is the case.
n_diff <- function(n_orig = 5, sig.level = 0.05) {
  tsample <- 2 # two.sample
  tside <- 1 # one.sided
  power <- 0.5
  
  # given sig.level and n_orig, determine delta/sd
  # i.e. solve t_crit = delta/(sigma * sqrt(n_orig/2)) for delta/sigma
  # (assuming a specific t_crit based on the p-value)
  delta_sd <- qt(sig.level, df = (n_orig-1)*tsample, lower.tail = FALSE)/sqrt(n_orig/2)
  
  ## determine n
  p.body <- quote({
    nu <- pmax(1e-07, n - 1) * tsample
    pt(qt(sig.level/tside, nu, lower.tail = FALSE), nu, ncp = sqrt(n/tsample) * 
         delta_sd, lower.tail = FALSE)
  })
  n <- uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2, 1e+07), 
               tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, extendInt = "upX")$root
  n_orig - n
}

n_diff(n_orig = 10000, sig.level = 0.01) # 0.2499987
n_diff(n_orig = 100, sig.level = 0.4) # 0.2521586

